# Can A Single Shared Mailbox Have Multiple ProxyAddress Entries/Aliases?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, email-server

Exchange 2010

We have a shared mailbox in our environment (foo@subdomain.example.com) that was renamed to foo2@example.com.  This ended up causing issues for applications that relied on the old SMTP address.

Is there a way to assign multiple email addresses to the same Shared Mailbox? I know individual users/mailboxes can have aliases but I wasn't sure if the same could be done for a shared mailbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this regard, a Shared mailbox is no different from an ordinary User mailbox, you can add additional email addresses just the same:

```
Set-Mailbox "foo2@example.com" -EmailAddresses @{add="foo@subdomain.example.com"}
```

If the email address is being removed due to Automatic email address policy updates, you can disable address policies for the mailbox:

```
Set-Mailbox "foo2@example.com" -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $False
```

If you want to use EMC and not the shell, go to **Recipient Configuration** -> **Mailbox**, right-click and select "Properties" on the mailbox and switch to the **Email Addresses** tab.